# Why can credentials not be located by aws cli when inside a container?

Tags: aws-cli

I am able to authenticate to aws when using the cli on my host machine and run commands:

```bash
aws sso login --profile ProfileName
aws s3 ls | wc -l
```

output:

```
➜  aws sso login --profile ProfileName
Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your default browser.
If the browser does not open or you wish to use a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:

https://device.sso.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

Then enter the code:

LGWW-BETZ
Successfully logged into Start URL: https://hfsso.awsapps.com/start
➜  aws s3 ls | wc -l
     438
```

However if I try attempting the same in a container after mounting the .aws directory it does not work:

```bash
➜  docker run --rm -ti -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli s3 ls

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

(That `docker run` command was copied from https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli)

I do not know why this is failing and I'm hoping someone can tell me why. It was my understanding that everything the cli requires is in `~/.aws`.

In case it helps, here is the contents of `~/.aws` on my host

```bash
➜  ls -la ~/.aws
drwxr-xr-x@    - username 24 Mar 14:23 cli
.rw-r--r--@ 3.6k username  4 Apr 09:10 config
drwxr-xr-x@    - username 24 Mar 14:23 sso
```

---

Responding to mark-b in the comments who asked:

> Are you sure you are running the AWS CLI as root in the container, since you are mapping it to /root/.aws? What happens if you create a shell in the container and do ls -l ~/.aws?

Here's what happens when I attempt that:

```bash
➜  docker run --rm -ti -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli s3 ls

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
➜  docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws --entrypoint bash amazon/aws-cli -c "ls -l ~/.aws"
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   96 Mar 24 14:23 cli
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 3569 Apr  4 08:10 config
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   96 Mar 24 14:23 sso
➜  docker run --rm -ti -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws --entrypoint bash amazon/aws-cli
bash-4.2# ls -l ~/.aws
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   96 Mar 24 14:23 cli
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 3569 Apr  4 08:10 config
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   96 Mar 24 14:23 sso
bash-4.2# echo $HOME
/root
```

Comment: There is no `credentials` directory there in `~/.aws` where aws basically stores the credentials and that's you are asking to run `aws configure`

Comment: Right. But that doesn’t explain why it works on the host and not in the container. There is no `credentials` directory on the host either.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the AWS CLI as root in the container, since you are mapping it to `/root/.aws`? What happens if you create a shell in the container and do `ls -l ~/.aws`?

Comment: Hello @MarkB, thanks for the reply. I have responded in an update to the original post.

Comment: I suspect you have an environment variable locally defining the profile to use which does not exist in the container. Try adding `--profile ProfileName` to the `s3 ls` within the container. `aws configure list` and `aws configure list --profile ProfileName` are useful to see where creds coming from.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 spot on, thank you :) I had `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` set on the host. this works -> `docker run --rm -ti -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli s3 ls --profile $AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`. If you post that as an answer I shall mark it as such. Thank you again.